# Start of selection triggered

Tags: abap

I understand that `START-OF-SELECTION` is triggered when the user executes the program (after the selection screen), but still there is something missing.
Example:
If I have the code:

```
gv_var = 2.
INITIALIZATION.
gv_var = 1.
```

the initialization code will be executed first, but if I have:

```
gv_var = 2.
START-OF-SELECTION.
gv_var = 1.
```

Start-of-selection will not be the first thing executed after the user executes.
So my question is: What exactly is the point of `START-OF-SELECTION` if it is not the first thing that is executed after the selection screen?
Is it just to make the program easier to read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to refresh your knowledge about [Event Blocks in Executable Programs](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/9f/db99fa35c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm?frameset=/en/9f/db9a1435c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/d3/2e974d35c511d1829f0000e829fbfe/plain.htm&node_id=363&show_children=false). `INITIALIZATION` is run before `START-OF-SELECTION`, and even before the display of the selection screen. The other important information is

> In an executable program, any non-declarative statements that occur
>   between the `REPORT` or `PROGRAM` statement and the first processing block
>   are also processed in the `START-OF-SELECTION` block.

(described [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/9f/db9a9635c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm?frameset=/en/9f/db9a2e35c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/d3/2e974d35c511d1829f0000e829fbfe/plain.htm&node_id=367))

Comment: Well, first of all I was using INITIALIZATION just for comparison reasons. If I understand correctly what you are saying the computer sees my second piece of code like : START-OF-SELECTION. gv_var = 2. gv_var = 1. ?

Comment: It depends - essentially on whether there's any other event instruction in the code above that you didn't quote.